# redundant encoding?

Tags: encoding, redundancy, information-theory

This is more of a computer science / information theory question than a straightforward programming one, so if anyone knows of a better site to post this, please let me know.

Let's say I have an N-bit piece of data that will be sent redundantly in M messages, where at least M-1 of those messages will be received successfully. I am interested in different ways of encoding the N-bit piece of data in fewer bits per message. (this is similar to [RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) but at a much smaller level, where N = 8 or 16 or 32)

Example: suppose N = 16 and M = 4. Then I could use the following algorithm:

```
1st and 3rd message: send "0" + bits 0-7
2nd and 4th message: send "1" + bits 8-15
```

If I can guarantee that 3 messages of the 4 will get through, then at least one message from each group will get through. Thus I can make this work with 9 bits or less, there's probably a way to do this with fewer total bits but I'm not sure how.

Are there some simple encoding/decoding algorithms to do this kind of thing? *Does this problem have a name?* (if I know what it's called, I can google it!)

**note:** in my particular case, the messages either arrive correctly or do not arrive at all (no messages arrive with errors).

(edit: moved 2nd part to a separate question)

Comment: (this isn't homework, by the way)

Comment: Do the messages arrive in random order (difficult)? Or are we allowed to assume that messages that arrive correctly always arrive in the order they were sent (easier)?

Comment: This was 2 years ago, I have no idea anymore. :-( (there should be a "no longer relevant" close button for the OP)

Answer (score 5):

(Incomplete answer follows. I may add more later.)

The term you may be interested in is *channel coding*: adding redundancy to a source in order to make it robust during transmission over a noisy channel. In information theory, the complementary problem to channel coding is *source coding*: reducing the redundancy in a source to represent it using fewer bits. (The combination of these two problems is called *joint source-channel coding*.)

Your first question asks to find a channel code. The simple example you give is similar to a *repetition code*, i.e., you send the same message more than twice (usually an odd number of times), and then the message which is received most often is accepted as the original message.

This code is inefficient. To use standard notation, let k = number of bits in original message, and n = number of bits in the transmitted message. For your example, k = 16 and n = 36. A measure of *coding efficiency* is k/n, where higher means more efficient. In your case, k/n = 0.44. This is low.

The repetition code is a simple kind of *block code*, i.e., redundancy is added to each block of k bits to create a codeword of n bits. So are the *Hamming* and *Reed-Solomon* codes as others mentioned. Hamming codes are relatively easy to understand with some basic linear algebra.

These should be enough terms for you to search on your own. Good luck.

Comment: In his example, n=36, not 64. (4*9=36)

Comment: I have no idea where I got 64.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understood all the details of your question correctly, but your problem is definitely aboud designing some kind of [error correcting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction#Error-correcting_code). This is a vast area of computer science and thick tomes have been written about it. Start with wikipedia and see if you can get any simple schemes (like Hamming or Reed-Solomon codes) to work in your case.

If you want to deal not only with symbol corruption, but also deletion of symbols, you should look at [erasure codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code), this is definitely a more difficult task but good methods exist in many cases.

EDIT: [This material from hackersdelight.org](http://www.hackersdelight.org/ecc.pdf) seems a nice introduction.

Answer (score 1):

See [erasure codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_codes).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a packet erasure code.  There are only two useful packet erasure codes that are not totally encumbered by patents, and there's only one open-source library to implement those.  Find it here: http://planete-bcast.inrialpes.fr/rubrique.php3?id_rubrique=5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivially simple scheme that's almost twice as efficient as your example.

You chopped the message into blocks of (N/M)*2 bits. Instead, chop it into N/(M-1)-bit blocks. (Round it up if necessary.) The first block, `src[0]`, encodes as itself: `enc[0]=src[0]`. The same for the last block: `enc[M-1]=src[M-1]`. Each of the other blocks gets XORed with its left neighbor: `enc[i]=src[i-1]^src[i]`.

Prefix each encoded block with a log(M)-bit sequence number, essentially as you did, so the receiver can tell which was dropped. (If you can be sure that whichever blocks arrive will arrive in order, then a 1-bit sequence number will do. Just alternate 0 and 1.)

To decode, successively XOR from the left and the right until you hit the dropped block. E.g. `src[1] == enc[0]^enc[1]`. (Dropping one of the endpoint blocks isn't a special case -- e.g. if the first block is dropped, the scan from the right recovers it, and the scan from the left is of length 0.)